# Test Class - System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending - Platform Event

Tags: apex, dml, future, platform-event

I am using platform events and in one of the after triggers I am calling a method in a class where the method is annotated with @Future(Callout=true)

In my test method below I am doing some DML to insert an account and opportunity record **before** I call Test.startTest().  My code is below, but I keep getting the "You have uncommitted work pending" error.

```
//insert dml here..

List<Job_Posting__e> jobPostingList = new List<Job_Posting__e>();

Job_Posting__e jobPosting = new Job_Posting__e();
jobPosting.jobTitle__c = 'Java Developer';
jobPosting.jobLocation__c = 'Raleigh, NC';
jobPostingList.add(jobPosting);

Test.startTest();

Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ServiceHttpResponseMock());

List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(jobPostingList);

Test.stopTest();
```

If I move the the line with EventBus.publish(jobPostingList) **after** Test.stopTest() the error goes away, but I *think* that line should be within the Test.start() and Test.stopTest() shouldn't it?

How can I resolve this error given the code above?

Comment: N.B.   You can coerce platform event delivery before reaching Test.stopTest() by using `Test.getEventBus().deliver()`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, The async Apex will be executed only at point `Test.stopTest()`. So, when you are moving the `EventBus.publish(jobPostingList)` line after stopTest, it is never getting executed and so your future callout method will not even be covered in test.

---

**Based on comment from @sfdcfox**

I tested this again. It seems `future` callout from platform event trigger without `stopTest` is not executing but same future method from account trigger (after insert) is getting invoked without `stopTest`.  (Have to do further testing for different types of objects). However this will not affect the current question in context - You need to check for DMLs in future method before callout.

---

Note that below test class will run without any problem:

```
@isTest
static void test(){
    Test.startTest();
    insert new Account(Name='test');
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AnimalsHttpCalloutMock());
    List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(new List<POC_Platform_Event__e>{new POC_Platform_Event__e()});
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Although I have callout in Event trigger, above test method will be success. Thats because the actual callout is separated into separate transaction by using `future`.

However, the moment I introduce DML statement in `future` method before callout I get the `uncommitted` error. Below callout will give error:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void mycallout(){
    insert new Account(Name='new test');
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
}
```

When I remove the line `insert new Account(Name='new test');`, the test class will be success again.

**You need to check in your future method if there are DIRECT OR INDIRECT (through other class references/triggers) DMLs happening. There is no prob with your test class.**

Comment: Async code run after test.stoptest is [still run](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/173723/2984), FYI. The rest of the answer is fine, though.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox. I just checked it again. I have future callout in platform event trigger (after insert). That is not even invoked without `stopTest`. Do you think something has changed in last 2 years? (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173723/future-runs-in-test-without-test-stoptest-can-that-be was from May' 17)

Comment: Strange, for platform event its not triggering without stoptest, but for account trigger its invoking.

Comment: Yeah, in my answer, I stated it may be a bug. The test from then still fails. It may have something to do with Platform Events and how they "test." I did +1 your answer, though, just correcting the bit about asynchronous code not running after Test.stopTest(). There are situations where it does, and one should be aware of this feature.

Comment: Thanks!.. @sfdcfox.. Added that bit in answer